# Problems with Sockets in C(function accept)

Tags: c, sockets

When i create that socket, exec the function accept but this function cause a warning and i dont know why, anyone can help me?, a fragment of my code is

```
serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
checkError( (serv_sock < 0), "cliente: no puedo abrir un socket TCP\n");
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=0;
bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
listen(serv_sock,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
while(clilen > 0){
     sockfd = accept(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

Ant the warning is: `passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'socklen_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]`

Comment: What type is `clilen`? If it's not type `socklen_t`, then change it to type `socklen_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your declaration of `clilen`?

It should be declared:

```
socklen_t clilen;
```

whereas based on the compiler warning I believe you have used:

```
int clilen;
```

Comment: I change this but the funcion return -1

Comment: @Ivang that's a separate question

Answer (score 0):

#### It’s important to also:

1. `memset_explicit`/`memset_s`/`memset` BSD socket API function structures before filling them in with values and passing as in-only parameters, or results maybe nondeterministic.
2. Always check return values of system calls and use `perror` to give users more info.
3. Set `SO_REUSEADDR` using `setsockopt` before calling `bind` or feel free to crash.

#### Resources

- [Here’s a very good portable C example (pdf)](http://computing.northumbria.ac.uk/staff/cgmb3/teaching/sockets/2CExamples/1_TCP_C_Donahoo_Lstgs.pdf)
- [Beej’s guide to sockets](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)
- [Berkely networking course slides with diagrams (pptx)](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee122/fa10/notes/03-Socket-Programming.pptx)

Comment: the problem is that the server doesnt send and and receibe anything and i dont know why

Comment: @Ivang: This would do as another question.